# Cocos2d-x lua binding

Tags: c++, binding, lua, cocos2d-x

After some researches, i found that Cocos2d-x lua is binding on top of C++, which make sense to me, since Cocos2d-x is c++ version of Cocos2d. But when I saw this [Wiki](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Lua_Binding), it seems they have some sort of information about binding c++ and java to lua, but when I clicked the link it said to be determined. And this confuse me a little, why Cocos2d-x lua still need to bind C++ to it?

I looked into Luabind [here](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html), it stated that "It (Luabind) has the ability to expose functions and classes, written in C++, to Lua. It will also supply the functionality to define classes in lua and let them derive from other lua classes or C++ classes." And I still not quit getting it, what is binding and what does it do actually?

If you know any good source or good tutorial to teach how to bind C++ and java to Cocos2d-x lua, I would very appreciate you share here.

Thank you in advance for your time and answers

Answer (score 3):

Cocos2d-X uses tolua(++) as its binding mechanism and not Luabind. The principle remains the same though. Both frameworks provide ways for the user to specify which classes/methods will be available in Lua, and how Lua should treat those objects.

This is called "binding" and typically involves generating wrapper code for methods and classes, which is cumbersome and error prone to maintain if you were to do this manually. Lua binding frameworks trade some speed and efficiency for ease of use and correctness.

If you want to learn tolua I suggest you start with the [tolua documentation](http://www.codenix.com/~tolua/) as well as looking at cocos2d-x examples for Lua bindings.